# Ruby on rails post request routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing, http-post

I am a newbie in the world of ruby on rails, and trying to find out how routing works. I read some articles about it but something is not clear to me.
 
If I have a page, with a message sender form and try to send the data via post, I have to set the route sg like this:

```
post '/send', to: 'message#send'
```

with this it works fine. But what if I have an another page with another form and I want to link it to another controller/action(post request too). How can It make a disctinction between the 2 posts?

Comment: Just have it post to another endpoint / route.  Routes exist as as way to match uri to controller/action.  So just create another route to the action you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass some special parameter and check it's value in controller, for instance:

```
class MessageController < ApplicationController
  def send
    if params[:kind] == 'some_value'
      do_one_thing
    else
      do_anoter_thing
    end
  end
end
```

But in this case your action will become fat and ugly. Thus I suggest you to create new action and separate logic in a natural way:

```
post '/my_send_from_one_place', to: 'message#my_send_from_one_place'
post '/my_send_from_secong_place', to: 'message#my_send_from_secong_place'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Its almost clear now, one more question, the first parameter '/my_send_from_second_place' is the path to the form?